# Rails subquery always returns nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I need to count rows from other table in subselect, so I use this query:

```
follows_sql = Follow.where(followable_type: 'Idea').where('follows.followable_id = ideas.id').select('COUNT(followable_id)').to_sql

idea = Idea.select("(#{follows_sql}) AS fcnt").includes(:collaborations).
  where(collaborations: { user_id: 4, owner: true })
```

So its produced valid SQL, but I cant access 'fcnt' value from idea var. I tried do it in different ways like:

```
idea[0].fcnt   # return nil
idea[0]["fcnt"]  # return nil
```

But I only can access fields which exists in a Idea model.
How I can access my custom '**fcnt**' field?
[image]

Comment: What does `idea[0].attributes` say?

Comment: list of all idea's attributes, which exists in database

Comment: `attributes` hash on the model contains all fetched fields of each row of the corresponding result set. Apparently the selection fell out at some point. Well...

Comment: see my update screen,  you will see that SQL looks fine

Comment: `AS t0_r0` obviously lost your alias at that point...

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you describe your tables and what you are trying to query?

Comment: I think it has no sense beacause, sql returns valid number for 'fcnt' column

Comment: "count rows from joined table" shows me that you have a misconception what a database join is.

Comment: Describe what you want, try to be exact, but do not use database terms like "join". describe what you have, the models and their relations. Then somebody clever will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think something along the following should work for you

```
idea = Idea.select("ideas.*, COUNT(follows.id) AS fcnt").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN follows ON follows.followable_id = ideas.id").group("ideas.id")

ideas.each do |idea|
  puts idea.fcnt
  # Should output a number
end
```

Note that I've left out the other includes and where clauses.  Try to solve the problem first, and if this query works out, then add in your additional clauses.

Also, if you setup your relations correctly, such that an idea has many follows, you could clean up your code by doing something like

```
ideas = Idea.includes(:collaborations).where(collaborations: { user_id: 4, owner: true })

ideas.map { |idea| idea.follows.count }
```

Comment: Yeah, `includes` seems to blow stuff up into the SQL hell. But we have to wait for a specific description of the problem to suggest solutions.